# ¿Cómo realizar esta consulta en laravel con query builder?

Tags: laravel, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql y necesito replicar lo mismo en laravel

> update aniversario set fecha = DATE(DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL 1 YEAR));

Comment: puedes poner lo que has intentado? como se llama tu clase?

Comment: porque no la mete en una funcion o en un sp dentro de la BD y luego solo lo manda a llamar desde laravel

Answer (score 0):

Yo realizo un post de esta forma
Podrias usar Carbon para obtener esa fecha el interval  tendrias que buscar la forma eso si tengo duda

```
 $post->nombre = $request->get('nombre');
        $post->excerpt = $request->get('excerpt');
        $post->descripcion = $request->get('descripcion');
        $post->published_at = Carbon::now();
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.bolsadetrabajo.vertrabajo', $post);
```

Comment: Lo que neccesito es ejecutar esa misma consulta en laravel. la idea es que tengo una tabla aniversario donde guardo fecha y necesito hacer que con esa consulta cambie el año de todos mis registro de mi tabla.